# Recursive Permissions fail on Synology SSH CLI

Tags: synology

I have tried the linked below fix for recursive inherited permissions, including steps in the comments (below), although there always is parts of the folder hirachy where inherited permissions arent applied, which makes for a total pain trying to give the SyncThing user group all permissions.

Is there a solution for [this](https://automatica.com.au/2016/11/recursively-propagate-permissions-on-a-synology-nas-with-synoacltool/)?!

```
find /volume1/Share\ Point -mindepth 1 ! -path '*/@eaDir*' ! -path '*/#recycle*' ! -path '*/#snapshot*' -execdir synoacltool -enforce-inherit {} \;
```

Some random directories aren't being included in the results. I'm not sure if the command is written incorrectly.

Settings for synoacltool are [here](https://www.synology-wiki.de/index.php/Synology_Toolset)